# ASP.NET/IIS rewriting 302 responses as 200

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net-4.0, ext.net

I want to use `Response.Redirect` to redirect to a new URL containing query string values like so:

```
Response.Redirect("http://www.example.org/?key1=value1&key2=value2");
```

This returns the following response to the browser, causing it to request the new page:

```
{script:"window.location=\"http://www.example.org/?key1=value1&key2=value2\";"}
```

Unfortunately, IE11 and Google Chrome handle this differently. IE11 behaves as one might expect, however Chrome HTML-encodes this response, causing the browser to redirect to `http://www.example.org/?key1=value1&amp;key2=value2`, which is obviously not what I want. How can I use `Response.Redirect` to behave as expected in both browsers?

Edit:

For clarity, the sequence of events is as follows:

1. Click a button on the page, which POSTs a `form` to the server
2. The server-side code runs, which includes a call to `Response.Redirect`.
3. In response to the POST, the browser receives a 200 containing `{script:"window.location=\"http://www.example.org/?key1=value1&key2=value2\";"}`
4. The browser makes a GET to the URL - either to the one shown in the response in the case of IE, or to the HTML-encoded version in the case of Chrome.

Edit2:

I've updated my code to explicitly do a 302 Redirect instead of using `Response.Redirect` however it still behaves the same way! The 302 gets replaced with the JS redirect somewhere along the line! Does anyone know of any settings anywhere (in code or in IIS) that might cause this behaviour? My new redirect code is:

```
private void ExplicitRedirect(string url)
{
    Response.StatusCode = 302;
    Response.RedirectLocation = url;
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: Something is not adding up.  So first off you are using two different redirection methods.   Response.Redirect is the server sending a redirection to the client ... probably some 404 or 401 status method with a alternative URL (you could look this code up).  The window.location redirection is totally different.  Javascript is forcing the window to load an alternative URL ... after the page has already loaded.  You wouldn't use both!  Response.redirect will work in all browsers during a postback.

Comment: I thought Response.Redirect worked by sending a 302 to the client but checking the network logs in both developer tools, in both cases it gets a 200 with the script shown in the question.

Comment: Thanks for looking up the code (302).  Are you sure that the browser doesn't do an internal redirect then return a 200 for the redirected page?  I do redirects all the time and I've never had an issue with browser support.  When you go window.location you are relying on javascript support and that can change from IE to webkit.

Comment: I've double checked the browser network logs, there are no 302 Redirects. There's a POST to the URL which triggers the call to `Response.Redirect` in my server code, which returns the JS response (200) shown in the question. The next event is the browser doing a GET on the HTML-encoded URL.

Answer (score 1):

This project uses Ext.Net which apparently alters the behaviour of `Response.Redirect`. Using Ext.Net's own `Redirect` method still uses JS instead of 302 but for some reason this method works as expected.